# Best Datasource Configuration for UITableView with Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have an array

```
    secInfArr = []
    let secInf1 = SecInfObj.init()
    secInf1.selected = true
    secInf1.itemName = "item1"
    secInf1.sectionName = "section3"
    secInfArr.append(secInf1)

    let secInf2 = SecInfObj.init()
    secInf2.selected = true
    secInf2.itemName = "item1"
    secInf2.sectionName = "section1"
    secInfArr.append(sectionInfo2)

    let secInf3 = SecInfObj.init()
    secInf3.selected = true
    secInf3.itemName = "item1"
    secInf3.sectionName = "section1"
    secInfArr.append(secInf3)

    let secInf4 = SecInfObj.init()
    secInf4.selected = false
    secInf4.itemName = "item1"
    secInf4.sectionName = "section2"
    secInfArr.append(secInf4)
```

and I want to create a `tableView` where all of this content is grouped by the `sectionName` property, and all the `itemName`s that are in that section are sorted alphabetically.

So far, I am doing what I think is inefficient. I am doing a `Distinct` operation on the `sectionName` property in the array, and then using it to name the sections and count them. After that, in the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method I just filter the array using the `sectionName`, and add the cells.

I have also thought of using `NSFetchedResultsController` but I don't think it will be such a good idea, since the data is not persistent in nature and therefore doesn't need to be in a `managedObject` form.

What is the ideal way of structuring the data for a grouped table view in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend an object oriented solution for example a struct with a `name` property and an `items` array, here in a generic form.

```
struct Section<T> {

    let name : String
    var items = [T]()

}
```

If the `items` array is mutated frequently use a `class` rather than a `struct` to take advantage of the reference semantics.

When populating the data source assign the `SecInfObj` objects to the appropriate `Section` instance.

The items can be sorted easily, you can declare your data source

```
var data = [Section<SecInfObj>]()
```

In `numberOfRows` return

```
return data[section].items.count
```

You get the section by index path with

```
let section = data[indexPath.section]
```

and then the items with

```
let items = section.items[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Vadian. 

Basically, I don't have control over the data, I receive it in the form that I described from the web service. What is the most efficient way, without nested for loops, to convert them to the said Struct?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make them separately into different arrays based on section. It is much easier to be called in datasource especially for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` methods. It also easy for UITableView to get data for each cells since it access directly to arrays by its index.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return items0.count
    }
    else if section == 1 {
        return items1.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

or also could be similarly like below. If all are seperately into `items[0] ... items [n]`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return items[section].count
}
```